# Wordpress static front-page made up of child pages

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to make a static front-page made up of child pages, surrounded by sections, like this:

```
Front Page
<div class="main">
Parent Start

 <section id="<section title>">
   Child Content
 </section>

 <section id="<section title>">
   Child Content
 </section>

 <section id="<section title>">
   Child Content
 </section>

Parent End
</div>
```

I was thinking the section id could be added from the menu settings?

Appreciate if anybody could point me in the right direction!

**SOLUTION**

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'meta_key'         => 'priority',
    'orderby'          => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'            => 'ASC',        
    'post_type'        => 'page',       
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'add_to_front_page',
            'value'   => 'Yes',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),

);
$pages = get_posts( $args );


foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $title = $page->post_title;
    $content = wpautop( $page->post_content );

}
```

`priority` and `add_to_front_page` are custom fields!

Comment: So the home page's children are the sections, and each section has a number of children pages of its own? Or do you mean that each section is just a grouping of pages with no real relation between them?

Comment: saying "child-pages", do you mean *posts*?

Comment: Don't put your solution in the question. You can answer it yourself as an answer. However, in your solution you're using a poor practice for getting pages. Rather than `get_posts()` with a `foreach` loop, it's safer and better to use WP_Query, as I've stated below.

Answer (score 1):

Use [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

```
<div class="main">
<?php
   $args = array(
          'posts_per_page'   => -1,
          'meta_key'         => 'priority',
          'orderby'          => 'meta_value_num',
          'order'            => 'ASC',        
          'post_type'        => 'page',       
          'post_status'      => 'publish',
          'meta_query' => array(
             array(
               'key'     => 'add_to_front_page',
               'value'   => 'Yes',
               'compare' => '=',
             ),
          ),

    );
   $query = new WP_Query( $args );
   while($query->have_posts() ):
     $query->the_post() : ?>

       <section id="<section title>">
         <?php  the_title();
                the_content(); ?>
       </section>
 <?php
   endwhile;
   wp_reset_postdata();
 ?>
</div>
```